# Wrong sed with regexp

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have log file. I want extract email list from specific lines.
Sample log file:

```
05:06:48,311  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-81 controller.IndexController:221 - Attempt to login: [xxx@yyy.com]. Headers: ["content-length": "52", ...]
15:06:48,311  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-81 controller.IndexController:221 - Attempt to login: [xxx@yyy.com]. Headers: ["content-length": "52", ...]
09:40:21,187  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-31 security.AuthAuthenticationProvider:81 - User: [16167]. Wrong code. Telegram: [0]. Google: [0]
```

My script:

```
cat file.log | sed -r 's/.*Attempt to login: \[(.*)\]\..*/\1/' | sort | uniq > file.log.filtered.txt
```

I get file.log.filtered.txt:

```
09:40:21,187  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-31 security.AuthAuthenticationProvider:81 - User: [16167]. Wrong code. Telegram: [0]. Google: [0]
xxx@yyy.com
```

Why I have line with "AuthAuthenticationProvider" in filtered file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are running your `sed` command only on lines which contains : `Attempt to login` so other lines will stay untouched.

You can change your code like this:

```
grep 'Attempt' file.log | sed -r 's/.*Attempt to login: \[(.*)\]\..*/\1/' | sort | uniq > file.log.filtered.txt
```

so it exclude the other lines first, then extracts email addresses.

or this one:

```
sed -re 's/.*Attempt to login: \[(.*@.*)\]\..*/\1/;t;d' file.log | sort | uniq
```

or even this one:

```
sed -nr 's/.*Attempt to login: \[(.*@.*)\]\..*/\1/p' file.log | sort | uniq
```

Or just use grep:

```
grep 'Attempt' file.log | grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' | sort | uniq
```

Regex for last command form [here](https://rietta.com/blog/2013/10/11/grep-extract-e-mail-addresses-from-a-text-file/)